# Unmanaged char * array to managed System::String in managed C++

Tags: c++, c++-cli, marshalling

I can't figure out what's wrong with my code here. This is used to create the array fontNames from my unmanaged C++ code, which is then retrieved in C#. The C# code simply outputs an array of blank strings. (This is not a problem for my other array of ints which uses the same approach).

Note the array of fontnames outputted by exportFontNames here works fine in C++ (it prints fine).

```
unsigned int fontNamesCount = 0;
const char ** unmanagedFontNames = o.exportFontNames(fontNamesCount);
array<String^>^ fontNames = gcnew array<String^>(fontNamesCount);
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < fontNamesCount; i++)
{
    fontNames[i] = gcnew String(unmanagedFontNames[i]);
    delete [] unmanagedFontNames[i];
}
delete [] unmanagedFontNames;
```

Can anyone see a reason why the resulting array of strings contains nothing? From my understanding, the constructor for gcnew String should make a copy of the unmanaged char array, so the delete shouldn't affect it (and removing the delete makes no difference). I'm stumped.

Comment: I've had similar problem a long time ago. AFAIR you need to marshal the data when you cross managed/unmanaged boundaries. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384865.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384859.aspx.

Comment: Bazurbat, thanks for the suggestion, I tried it but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this in the loop instead:

```
fontNames[i] = marshal_as<String^>(unmanagedFontNames[i]);
```

You will need some directives, too:

```
#include <msclr/marshal.h>
using namespace msclr::interop;
```